How can I extract "DXS" from "31DXS6070705.OUT"?
I have a dataset in which the Primary key column is in 31DXS6070705.OUT format.
How can I extract DXS from 31DXS6070705.OUT? Please note that for some records DXS(extracted part) may vary to either two letters or it may remain three letters.
I'm working with PostgreSQL.

A '^\d*([[:alpha:]]{2,3})([^\.]*)\.OUT$' regular expression pattern would work:

The caret ^ followed by \d* tells it the pattern starts with zero or more some digits. The caret ^ means the beginning of the pattern.
Parentheses () define subexpressions, which you can then select with the last parameter of regexp_substr(txt, pattern, start, N, flags, this_one_picks_the_subexpression).
[[:alpha:]]{2,3} Means between 2 and 3 alphabetic characters
The caret ^ in [^\.]* makes the square-bracketed character class accept anything except for the literal . dot inside. The dot is escaped with the backslash \. Otherwise, an unescaped dot would match any character.
\.OUT$ means the pattern ends with a literal dot . and uppercase OUT. The dollar $ means the end of the pattern.

Depending on whether you want the letters in the middle of the number, or the number following the letters, just switch the last parameter.
Demo at db<>fiddle:
WITH your_table(pk) AS (VALUES 
  ('31DXS6070705.OUT'),('31DX6070706.OUT'),('31ABC6070707.OUT'))
SELECT regexp_substr(pk,'^\d*([[:alpha:]]{2,3})([^\.]*)\.OUT$',1,1,'',1) 
       AS extracted_part
FROM your_table;




extracted_part




DXS


DX


ABC



WITH your_table(pk) AS (VALUES 
  ('31DXS6070705.OUT'),('31DX6070706.OUT'),('31ABC6070707.OUT'))
SELECT regexp_substr(pk,'^\d*([[:alpha:]]{2,3})([^\.]*)\.OUT$',1,1,'',2) 
       AS extracted_part
FROM your_table;




extracted_part




6070705


6070706


6070707



